# How can I load this dataset to Keras or TF?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to `Keras` and `TF`. I need to load this dataset:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/letter-recognition/letter-recognition.data

But every tutorial I've seen uses built in methods with loading from MNIST dataset.
I came up with changing letter(label) to `int(like a->1,b->2,c->3 etc.)`
But how to split this into 2 sets (x-in, y-out)?

Comment: What does the columns in the dataset represent?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/letter-recognition/letter-recognition.names
Letter category and 16 numeric features. @nuric

Comment: What is the target variable (y-out)? Is it the 1st column which is letters?

Comment: @heenabawa yes it is

Comment: Have you tried train_test_split() or slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But every tutorial I've seen uses built in methods.

I would recommend using pandas if you haven't tried before.

1. First copy paste the data and save as a csv file(example.csv).
2. Every csv file requires header, since this file doesn't have by default you can add manually. By inserting 
   `alphabet, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16`
   at the top of the file. Note: You should replace the numbers with the actual feature name for more readability.
3. `import pandas as pd`
4. Read the file:

   `dataframe = pd.read_csv("example.csv")`
5. Since, you said the first column is the label you can drop that out of the dataframe.

   `y = dataframe["alphabet"]`
6. Remaining column are the input you can retrieve using `values` attribute which returns a numpy array.

   `x = dataframe.drop("alphabet", 1).values` #Drop along column
7. Now you can split the dataset using `train_test_split` in `sklearn.model_selection` or you can use python indices.

   ```
   test_size = 0.1
   train_samples = int(X_train.shape[0]*(1 - test_size))
   X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = x[:train_samples],x[train_samples: ], y[:train_samples], y[train_samples: ]
   ```

   or

   ```
   from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(x, y,
    test_size=test_size)
   ```
8. Now since y is numpy array of characters, we need to map it to indices.

   ```
   mapping = {}
   classes = set(y)
   for c in classes:
       if c not in mapping:
           mapping[c] = len(mapping)
   y = np.array([mapping[i] for i in y])
   ```
9. Now finally converting to one hot format:

   ```
   from keras.utils import to_categorical
   y = to_categorical(y, len(mapping))
   ```
10. This is usually the format MNIST dataset is stored, in most libraries. Further you can normalize the data up to your need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the file on your own.

For this you do something like this:

```
x_t = []
y_t = []
char_to_int = {}
int_to_char = {}
for i in x.split("\n"):
    print(i)
    y_t.append(i[0])
    x_t.append(i.split(",")[1:])

for i,j in enumerate(sorted(set(y_t))):
    char_to_int[j]=i 
for i,j in enumerate(sorted(set(y_t))):
    int_to_char[i]=j 
y_t = [char_to_int[i] for i in y_t]
```

Basically you iterate through the file and keep the integers as x values. For the y values you first take the letter. But the neural network won't understand this, so you need to build a dictionary with an integer to letter mapping. That's why we parse y again in the end, so that we end up with y values.

Now you only need to make numpy arrays out of this.

Answer (score 1):

For small datasets (as in your case), I would just parse from file and use iterator. Here's `TensorFlow` example for your data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

with open('data') as fo:
    labels_and_data = [x.split(',') for x in fo.read().split('\n')]

labels = [d[0] for d in labels_and_data]
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(d[1:], dtype=np.float) for d in labels_and_data])

# string labels to integers
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(labels)
encoded_labels = encoder.transform(labels)

# split data and create iterators
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, encoded_labels, test_size=0.2)
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'x': x_train, 'y': y_train}).batch(10)
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'x': x_test, 'y': y_test}).batch(10)
train_iter = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
test_iter = test_data.make_initializable_iterator()

# define your model here
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32)
n_epochs = 2

# train
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run([train_iter.initializer, test_iter.initializer])
    next_train_batch = train_iter.get_next()
    next_test_batch = test_iter.get_next()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        while True:
            try:
                batch = sess.run(next_train_batch)
                print(batch['x'])
                print(batch['y'])
                # feed_dict = {X: batch['x'], y: batch['y']}
                # evaluated_ops = sess.run(your ops here...,
                #                          feed_dict=feed_dict)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
                break
```